# Separating a list depending on logged in users id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag

I have list of `League`'s I pass to my View. The view should then determine whether or not the `Participant`'s id matches the `UserId` for the `User` that is logged in; who's Id is saved in `ViewBag`.

If the id matched I want to display the list under the `<p>Your kid(s):</p>`; else the `Participant`'s will be displayed under the `<p>Everybody else's kid(s):</p>`

---

**_DisplayEach.cshtml**

```
@model List<League>
@{
    <p>userId is: @ViewBag.UserId</p>
    <p>Your kid(s):</p>    
    {
    if (Model != null && Model.Any())
        foreach(League i in Model)
        {
            var userParticipants = i.allParticipants.Where(p => p?.child?.Parent?.UserId == @ViewBag.UserId).ToList();
            foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in userParticipants)
            {
                <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId</p>
            }  
        }
    }
    <p>Everybody elses kid(s):</p>
    if (Model != null && Model.Any())
    {

        foreach(League i in Model)
        {
            var allOtherUserParticipants = i.allParticipants.Where(p => p?.child?.Parent?.UserId != @ViewBag.UserId).ToList();
            foreach (MMLeagueParticipant mmLeagueParticipant in allOtherUserParticipants)
            {
                <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                <p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId</p>
            }  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p>the list is empty</p>
    }
}
```

**issues:**

The entire list is being displayed under the `<p>Everybody elses kid(s):</p>` regardless of if the UserId matching or not. And nothing under the `<p>Your kid(s):</p>`

error:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
I then looked at my controller to see how it may be coming back as null.

**Controller details:**

- in my controller I have a list of age groups that i add new `participant` models to.
- Then I pass the list to my `RosterPageBasketball` view.
- Inside that view I have 12 tabs; each displaying different lists depending on the age group.
- model used in RosterPageBacketball: `@model List<League>`
- Each tab in the RosterPageBasketball that displays different agegroups:

  @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["bbM7and8"])

each tab in my `RosterPageBasketball`contains the following code: `@await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["bbM#and#"])`

---

**DashboardController:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBasketballRoster()
{
    String[] leagueNames = new[]
    {
        "bbM7and8",
        "bbM9and10",
        "bbM11and12",
        "bbM13and14",
        "bbM15and16",
        "bbM17and18",
        "bbF7and8",
        "bbF9and10",
        "bbF11and12",
        "bbF13and14",
        "bbF15and16",
        "bbF17and18"
    };
        Dictionary<string, List<League>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<League>>();
        foreach (var name in leagueNames)
        {
            List<League> bbLeagues = await db.Leagues
            .Where(l => l.sport == "Basketball")
            .Where(l => l.ageRange==name)
            .ToListAsync();

            foreach (League league in bbLeagues)
            {
                List<MMLeagueParticipant> leagueParticipants = await db.Entry(league)
                    .Collection(l => l.allParticipants)
                    .Query() // <-- This is needed to allow for `Include()`
                    .Include(mmp => mmp.child)
                    .ToListAsync();
            }
            var data = bbLeagues.Where(l => l.sport == "Basketball").Where(l => l.ageRange == name).ToList();
            d.Add(name, data);
        }
        }
        ViewBag.UserId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
        Console.WriteLine("User Id is:"+ ViewBag.UserId);

        return View("RosterPageBasketball", d);
}
```

**Flow of data:**

- Dictionary<string, List> d is passed to the `RosterpageBasketball`
- `RosterpageBasketball` uses `@model Dictionary<string, List<League>>`
- _Displayeach view is passes a model["bbM#and#"]
- _Displayeach view uses `@model List<League>`

**where the issue might be:**`RosterPageBasketball.cshtml`

```
<div>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["bbM7and8"])
</div>
```

**What I tried (1):**

```
var data = Model.Where(a => a.Key == "bbF17and18").Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault();
<div>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", data)
</div>
```

**Results:**

This made no difference. The issue just went from `@await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", Model["bbM7and8"])` to `@await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", data)`.

The problem seems to be I can't locate the UserId from the model being passed in.

**What I tried (2):**

```
<p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLeagueParticipant.child.ParticipantLastName</p
<p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId</p>
```

If I Add `<p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId</p>` under my current p tag; the following error is displayed in browser:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

browser doesn't like:

- @mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId
- @await Html.PartialAsync("_Displayeach", data)

**Results:** when `<p>@mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent.UserId</p>` is commented out

- In the browser `<p>userId is: @viewBag.UserId</p>` the correct Id is displayed
- The first and last names of the participants were appearing on the screen as they needed to

**Where the issue might be(Uncertain):**
The place I am saving my Session is in HomeController. However the place I'm trying to call it is in my DashboardController. I do prefer to keep the log-in and register controller separate from my DashboardController.

**HomeController:**

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt3b2("UserId", dbUser.UserId);
ViewBag.UserId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.UserId); //<<--this works fine and shows the correct Id when I'm login in.
```

---

**model description and relationships:**

- one to many - one `User` has many `ViewModel.Participant`'s
- many to many - `ViewModel.Participant` and `League` share a `MMLeagueParticipant` middle table

---

My league model:

```
int LeagueId { get; set; }
string sport { get; set; }
string gender { get; set; }
string ageRange { get; set; }
```

​    List allParticipants  { get; set; }

---

My ViewModel model:

```
public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
public ViewModel.Participant participant { get; set; }

public class Participant
{
    int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
    string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
    string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
    system.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }

    List<MMLeagueParticipant> allLeagues { get; set; }

    int UserId { get; set; }
    User Parent { get; set; }
}
```

---

My MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:

```
int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
int LeaugeId { get; set; }
leauge sport { get; set; }

ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }
```

---

My User model:

```
int UserId { get; set; }
string FirstName { get; set; }
string LastName { get; set; }
string Email { get; set; }
string Password { get; set; }
strig ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

List<ViewModel.Participant> kids { get; set; }
```

Comment: Debug and see whether you get null for mmLeagueParticipant.child.Parent or mmLeagueParticipant.child objects.